# Unit Tests - Assert.ThrowAnyAsync doesn't handle derived class of Exception Class (Xunit)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, exception, xunit

I have code like that:

```
var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync<Exception>(async () => await _ftpClient.GetFile("test", "test"));
```

Method GetFile returns exception `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` which is derived class of Exception class but `ThrowsAnyAsync` method doesn't work for it.

I received an error:

```
Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: System.Exception
Actual:   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
```

Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Xunit or nunit? On nunit, you can use `CatchAsync<Exception>` to also catch derived exceptions

Comment: I am using Xunit

Comment: I added the corresponding Tag for you.

Answer (score 3):

In the doc comments for `Assert.ThrowsAsync` in the xunit code (see current version 3 at https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/ExceptionAsserts.cs) we can see:

```
/// Verifies that the exact exception is thrown (and not a derived exception type).
```

To also get derived types, the method `Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync` is provided

Doc comment:

```
/// Verifies that the exact exception or a derived exception type is thrown.
```

So you're correct to think that it should work in your case.

The `Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync` method eventually calls the following method which checks the type of the argument, `exceptionType` being the expected type, and `exception` being the actually thrown exception.

```
        static Exception ThrowsAny(
            Type exceptionType,
            Exception exception)
        {
            GuardArgumentNotNull(nameof(exceptionType), exceptionType);

            if (exception == null)
                throw new ThrowsException(exceptionType);

            if (!exceptionType.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(exception.GetType().GetTypeInfo()))
                throw new ThrowsException(exceptionType, exception);

            return exception;
        }
```

If the `IsAssignableFrom` is returning true, then everything should work.

This short test code of mine

```
        public static bool testAssignable()
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e = new SocketException();
            TypeInfo exceptionTypeInfo = typeof(Exception).GetTypeInfo();
            return exceptionTypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(e.GetType().GetTypeInfo());
        }
```

returns true as expected, so it should® work...

This test passes:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            var ex = Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync<Exception>(async () => await MUT());
        }

        private async Task MUT()
        {
            throw new System.Net.Sockets.SocketException();
        }
```

so it's working for me.

Your error message refers to Assert.IsType() failure. Are you checking the type yourself or is this message really coming from Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync?

There are some issues with Assert.IsType(), see [xunit testing web api 2 controller : throws Xunit.Sdk.IsTypeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465195/xunit-testing-web-api-2-controller-throws-xunit-sdk-istypeexception/37478239#37478239) and XUnit issue https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/860 which was never fixed and "closed for age". Could that be the cause of your problem?

Comment: I have this like that so I check type.

//Act
           `var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync<Exception>(async () => await _ftpClient.UploadFile(fileContent, "test","test"));`

            //Assert
           `Assert.IsType<Exception>(ex);`

Comment: Then you're pou're probably seeing the XUnit bug in the github link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465195/xunit-testing-web-api-2-controller-throws-xunit-sdk-istypeexception/37478239#37478239 contains a workaround, just checking the Name of the type.